# jQuery Tooltip using <title> doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, tooltip

I am having trouble displaying a tooltip from a title attribute on an anchor tag in IE. I have gotten it to work great in all other browsers.

There is alot of code to copy and paste into this window, so please visit the JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/nVsYS/1/
(roll-over the drop down menu options)

If anyone has a clue as to why this is happening I would appreciate any insight.
Thanks!

Comment: Z-index seems to be related - or at least, removing the `z-index` from the `a` element in IE's developer tools made the tooltip appear.  Couldn't replicate the fix by adjusting the CSS in jsFiddle, though.

Comment: Yeah, I've had the same experience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making it so the tooltip div's "tooltip" id is a class instead? So instead of `id="tooltip"`, let it be `class="tooltip"`, and reference it with `div.tooltip` instead of `div#tooltip`.